# How to append <g> element after grouping my circles in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a bunch of circles. I first visualize the circles as following:

```
circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(csv)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("id", function(d,i){return "id_" + i.toString();})
        .attr("class", function(d){return "Color_" + d.Cyl;})
        .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.Cyl);})
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return Scale.xScale(d.Weight); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return Scale.yScale(d.DealerCost); })
        .attr("r", r)
        .call(drag);
```

Then at some point in my code I use **nest()** function to group these circles based on a particular key.

```
var data = d3.nest()
                  .key(function(d) { return d.Cyl;})
                  .rollup(function(d) { 
                  return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return Number(g.value); });
    }).entries(csv);
```

And then update the position of the circles using following code

```
 for(j=0; j<data.length;j++)
    {
            svg        
                .selectAll(".Color_" + data[j].key)
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d,i) { return 100; })
                .duration(1000)
                .ease("linear")
                .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return Scale.xScale(data[j].key+ " Cylinder")+ (i%val)*r*2;})    
                .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return StachChartHeight - (Math.floor(i/val))*r*2;})
    }
```

I am trying to add each category of circles to the "g" element using following code but it does not work. In fact I need to have 3 different "g" tags which each contains a group of circles.

```
 for(j=0; j<data.length;j++)
    {
            svg 
                .append("g") // this is what I added       
                .selectAll(".Color_" + data[j].key)
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d,i) { return 100; })
                .duration(1000)
                .ease("linear")
                .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return Scale.xScale(data[j].key+ " Cylinder")+ (i%val)*r*2;})    
                .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return StachChartHeight - (Math.floor(i/val))*r*2;})
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but it sounds like you're adding circles to the SVG graphic and then at some later time you want to wrap (some of) those circles in a `<g>` element? If that's the question, then you'll need to remove the circles from the SVG graphic and re-append them within the newly added `<g>`. Just appending a `<g>` element doesn't do anything to the elements already in the graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like your comments say... One way to 'move' elements into another element with d3 is to select the elements, [remove](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#remove) them and then append them into another element. For you it would probably look something like this:

```
for(j=0; j<data.length; j++) {
    var circlesToMove = svg.selectAll(".Color_" + data[j].key).remove();
    svg.append("g")
       .data(circlesToMove).enter()
       .append(function(d){ return d.node(); });
}
```

Note that remove returns the selection after taking the elements out of the dom.